# Does ElasticsearchTemplate.scroll return the new scrollId?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data

When using the [Spring Data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.scan.and.scroll)'s [ElasticsearchTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/ElasticsearchTemplate.html) there is a `scroll` method for doing the Scan & Scroll technique. In the [Elasticsearch documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) you can find the following information:

> The initial search request and each subsequent scroll request returns a new _scroll_id — only the most recent _scroll_id should be used.

So I wonder how to get the new `_scroll_id` from Spring's `scroll()` method which I can then pass to the next `scroll()` call. Can I find it in the returned `Page`? I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue.

Elasticsearch logs are flooded with `org.elasticsearch.search.SearchContextMissingException: No search context found for id` .

This is not implemented in Spring Data Elasticsearch yet. There is already a JIRA ticket for this [DATAES-166](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-166) and a [pull request in github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/pull/120) that adds this kind of functionality.

Until this is finally merged, I just implemented this class

```
public class ScrollPage<T> extends PageImpl<T> {

    private String scrollId;

    public ScrollPage(List<T> content, String scrollId) {
        super(content);
        this.scrollId = scrollId
    }

    public String getScrollId() {
        return scrollId;
    }
}
```

And afterwards in my request I return a ScrollPage instead of Page and set the new scrollId from the elasticsearch response.

```
 String scrollId = elasticsearchTemplate.scan(searchQuery, 5000, false);
    List<Info> infos= new ArrayList<>();
    boolean hasRecords = true;
    while (hasRecords) {
        Page<Info> page = elasticsearchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L, new SearchResultMapper() {
            @Override
            public <T> ScrollPage<T> mapResults(SearchResponse response, Class<T> clazz, Pageable pageable) {
                List<Info> result = new ArrayList<>();
                for (SearchHit searchHit : response.getHits()) {
                    Info info= new Info();
                    String code= searchHit.getFields().get("code").getValue();
                    info.setCode(code)
                    result.add(info);
                }
                if (result.size() > 0) {
                   return new ScrollPage<T>((List<T>, response.getScrollId());
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
        if (page != null) {
            infos.addAll(page.getContent());
            scrollId = ((ScrollPage) page).getScrollId();
        } else {
            hasRecords = false;
        }
    }
```

This way elastic does not complaint anymore and the logs are clear.

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearchTemplate class has SearchResponse to get scrollId,but it only can be see in ElasticSearchTemplate Object such as :

```
@Override
public <T> Page<T> scroll(String scrollId, long scrollTimeInMillis, Class<T> clazz) {
    SearchResponse response = getSearchResponse(client.prepareSearchScroll(scrollId)
            .setScroll(TimeValue.timeValueMillis(scrollTimeInMillis)).execute());
    return resultsMapper.mapResults(response, clazz, null);
}
```

so for obtaining SearchReponse, you can create a esUtil extends ElasticSearchTemplate such as :

```
@Component
```

public class EsScrollUtil extends ElasticsearchTemplate {

```
public EsScrollUtil(Client client) {
    super(client);
}

    /**
 * query all by searchQuery from es
 * @author fujian
 *
 */
public <T> List<T> queryAll(SearchQuery searchQuery, Class<T> T) {

    String scrollId = scan(searchQuery, 5000l, false);

    List<T> entities = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean hasRecords = true;
    while (hasRecords) {
        SearchResponse searchResponse = getClient().prepareSearchScroll(scrollId).
                setScroll(new TimeValue(5000l)).execute().actionGet();

        Page<T> page = getResultsMapper().mapResults(searchResponse, T, null);
        if(page.hasContent()) {
            entities.addAll(page.getContent());
            scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId();
        } else {
            hasRecords = false;
        }
    }

    clearScroll(scrollId);

    return entities;

}
```

}